# Error while executing Invoke-Sqlcmd on Win server

Tags: sql-server, powershell, entity-framework-core

I want to update database with my migration located in "C:\migrations.sql" for my ASP.NET Core app with ef core.

I'm trying to execute below command in windows server power shell:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=testApp3db;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" -
InputFile "C:\migrations.sql"
```

but I get this error:

```
Cannot open database "testApp3db" requested by the login. The login failed.
```

database "testApp3" does not exist but the script has command to create this db. My user has all permissions in DB, I also tried to execute this command by Azure agent (by NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM) , it also has all permissions, but still the same error

How to fix it?

Comment: Either by not specifying `Initial Catalog=testApp3d`, or by issuing `CREATE DATABASE` first (unless the script already contains this). You can't connect to databases that don't exist.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert that's make sense, but this method executes me "update database" so why it not create me also database?

Comment: the script contains CREATE DATABASE command

Comment: Connecting to the server happens before any script is run. Telling it to connect to a database that doesn't exist fails before the script ever gets to create anything. Leave out the `Initial Catalog` setting and you'll connect to the default database of the user (which, unless otherwise configured, is `master`).

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert thank You ! One additional question is how I can add it to pipeline? for example in azure devops? its worth to add it or it's better to just manually create this db?

Comment: @jeroenMostert please make your comment an answer.